# Hover Event in Jquery does Nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

I have this javascript code that highlight's a navigation tab when it's hovered over, but whenever I hover with my mouse it does nothin. What should I do?

```
$("nav ul li").hover(
    function(){
        $("nav ul li").css("background-color","rgba(255,255,255,0.9)");
    },
    function(){
        $("nav ul li").css("background-color","");
    }
);
```

Comment: well that is going to highlight all the tabs if it were to work... Reason you do not use just CSS, there is really no need to use JavaScript.

Comment: use css for this, nav ul li:hover { background-color: #color }

Comment: So the issue is either you are binding before the element exists on the page or the selector is wrong. Impossible to tell with the code above. Basic console.log statements can help you figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is with CSS:

```
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

If you are forced to use JavaScript instead, you probably wanted to use `this` within your callback to identify the specific `li` that was hovered, see comments:

```
$("nav ul li").hover(
    function(){
        // Give this LI a specific background color  
        // and remove it from siblings, just in case 
        $(this).css("background-color","rgba(255,255,255,0.9)")
            .siblings("li")                                    
                .css("background-color","");
    },
    function(){
        // Remove it when we lose hover 
        $(this).css("background-color","");
    }
);
```

But that's very much a second-best option.

Comment: wouldin't it be `nav ul li:hover { background-color: ...} nav ul li { background: inherit; }` ?

Comment: lol never mind.

Comment: @Snowmonkey: Yes -- that's why I typed the colon, then apparently forgot to type hover, then got myself thoroughly confused. Thank you Brandon for the fix!

Comment: Or if you have to use js for the hover, but can still use css classes then use css classes.

Comment: @freedomn-m: Yeah, I almost even added that as I was answering...